# How do I change the welcome message in Magento 1.9+ the proper way?

Tags: blocks, ce-1.9.0.1, header

I would like to change the welcome message to just show initials. Clearly I can do something in the template, however, I would like to extend/over-ride Mage_Page_Block_Html_Welcome to do this 'the proper way'.

I have tried doing this however I cannot get it to work - I just get a blank line. I am expecting the normal line with 'TEST' written in there too:

Here is my config.xml entry:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <page>
            <rewrite>
                <html_welcome>MyCompany_Mymodule_Page_Block_Html_Welcome</html_welcome>
            </rewrite>
        </page>
    </blocks>
```

My code, just copied from the original file with a small change for test porpoises:

app/code/local/MyCompany/Mymodule/Block/Page/Html/Welcome.php

```
<?php class MyCompany_Mymodule_Page_Block_Html_Welcome extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Welcome {

    /**
     * Get block messsage
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
            if (Mage::isInstalled() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__('TEST Welcome, %s!', $this->escapeHtml(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName()));
            } else {
                $this->_data['welcome'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome');
            }
        }

        return $this->_data['welcome'];
    }

    /**
     * Get tags array for saving cache
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheTags()
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->addModelTags(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer());
        }

        return parent::getCacheTags();
    }
}
```

Comment: I do something related in my welcome block and it works. What happens if you just `$this->_data['welcome'] = "test.";` ? Are you trying to see message logged in ?

Comment: @Niloct - I tried as suggested but I could not get it working in my module - I think there is something else I need to do given the toHtml is a protected function. Is your code in a module and do you extend the original class? Do you have a template change?

Comment: Yeap, it's similar to your sample code. Have you enabled module in `etc/modules` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help - sometimes knowing that it can be made to work is all one needs to know. I actually had my class paths wrong -..._Block_Page_ was what I needed to match my file paths. Got there in the end!

Comment: Great! I sometimes mess up with path too =)

Answer (score 2):

No code is needed for this.

Go to System - Configuration - General - Design - Header and voila!

Comment: I would like to do more than change the default welcome message, I would like to add my own custom code to show initials, i.e. based on the customer's name. To do that I can put something ugly in the template to get the customer if they are logged in, to then get their name and then get their initials, however I would like to do this the proper magento way without making changes to the template. However, when I try to override-extend the the core code for the welcome message it does not work for me. I would like to know why that is. Thankyou.

Comment: You have the wrong approach. I suggest you closing this question or mark it as solved and start a new one with the correct info and your question, because with this one it seems you want to change the default welcome message from Magento and not the one when a customer is logged.

Comment: I answered my own question with the 'right approach'. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Simple mistake was made here - the class path did not match the file path:

app/code/local/MyCompany/Mymodule/Block/Page/Html/Welcome.php

required the config.xml and the 'extends' file to have MyCompany_Mymodule_Block_Page_Html_Welcome

Thanks to @Niloct I was able to correct this rather than it be something more complicated.

For anyone wanting to pull through just the first name, in app/code/local/MyCompany/Mymodule/Block/Page/Html/Welcome.php:

```
<?php class MyCompany_Mymodule_Block_Page_Html_Welcome extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Welcome {
    /**
     * Get block messsage
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
            if (Mage::isInstalled() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__('Welcome, %s!', $this->escapeHtml(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getFirstname()));
            } else {
                $this->_data['welcome'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome');
            }
        }

        return $this->_data['welcome'];
    }

}
```

Then in app/code/local/MyCompany/Mymodule/etc/config.xml:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <page>
            <rewrite>
                <html_welcome>MyCompany_Mymodule_Block_Page_Html_Welcome</html_welcome>
            </rewrite>
        </page>
    </blocks>
    ...
```

Then everything works fine.