# Customize Welcome Message Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, login, logout

Hi i want to customise my welcome message like this:

"hi visitor, welcome to %storename%! Log in or register."

but i don't know how i should include the login link, because if you logged in, the message will have to change like this: hi %username% you're logged in. logout?

or something else.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Maurice
Magento is managed  manged welcome message from

Mage_Page_Block_Html_Welcome class _toHtml() function

Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header class getWelcome function

Step1:Copy app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html.php

to  app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html.php

change code of getWelcome

```
if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
    if (Mage::isInstalled() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__(' hi %s% youre loggin in. <a href="%s">logout?</a>', $this->escapeHtml(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName()),Mage::helper('customr')->getLogoutUrl());
    } else {
        //$this->_data['welcome'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome');
    $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__('hi visitor,  to %s! <a  href="%s">Log<a> in or <a href="%s">register</a>', $this->escapeHtml(Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName()),Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(),Mage::helper('customer')->getRegisterUrl());

    }
}

return $this->_data['welcome'];
```

Step2:

Copy app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Welcome.php

to  app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Welcome.php

tohtml

```
if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
    if (Mage::isInstalled() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__(' hi %s% youre loggin in. <a href="%s">logout?</a>', $this->escapeHtml(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName()),Mage::helper('customr')->getLogoutUrl());
    } else {
        //$this->_data['welcome'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome');
    $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__('hi visitor,  to %s! <a  href="%s">Log<a> in or <a href="%s">register</a>', $this->escapeHtml(Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName()),Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(),Mage::helper('customer')->getRegisterUrl());

    }
}

return $this->_data['welcome'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How do I change the welcome message in Magento 1.9+ the proper way?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/how-do-i-change-the-welcome-message-in-magento-1-9-the-proper-way)

Then make changes to

```
/**
 * Get block messsage
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
        if (Mage::isInstalled() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            //change from
            //$this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__('Welcome, %s!', $this->escapeHtml(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getFirstname()));
            //to
            $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__('hi visitor, welcome to %s! . <a href="%s">Log in</a> or <a href="%s">register</a>', $this->escapeHtml(Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();), Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(),Mage::helper('customer')->getRegisterUrl();
        }
```